# Splitting a string in d programming language via whitespace where multiple whitespace can appear consecutively but should be treated as one

Tags: algorithm, d

I want to split a string in D programming language, so that elements that are empty strings, are not counted.

Example:

Input : `This is   a string` [Note that between `is` and `a`, there are 3 blank spaces]

Output: `[This, is, a, string]`

**Problem**

If I use the `std.array.split` [linked [here](https://dlang.org/library/std/array/split.html)] function with `" "` (blank space) as delimiter, then I get:  `["This", "is", " ", "a", "string"]`. See the blank element between `"is"` and `"a"`.

**My Current solution**

```
output = input.split(" ").filter!(l => !l.strip().empty).array;
```

Note, that this would also be possible if multiple consecutive blank spaces were treated as one.

**My question**

Does the split function (or an alternative) has a built in method to either:

- automatically treat multiple consecutive occurrence of the delimiter as one,
- automatically reject elements that are whitespace only

Either of these two will be sufficient for this particular example (I can't think of a counterexample)

I looked at Programming in D – Tutorial and Reference by Ali Çehreli [[here](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/)], but i can't seem to find this functionality. Does that mean in D you are supposed to use the filter and Lambda?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: another way of doing this would be to replace multiples blank space by a single one before splitting. But I don't know enough about the D language to help you further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` without any parameters does exactly what you are requesting:

```
When no delimiter is provided, strings are split into an array of words,
using whitespace as delimiter. Runs of whitespace are merged together
(no empty words are produced).
```

(this is a quote from the documentation which you linked to)

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply "strip" before "split" function.

```
output = input.strip.split;
```

Comment: does that remove multiple whitespaces __inside__ the string?

Comment: Yes, as Steven clarified in his answer it will handle spaces inside as well. With strip you can remove some extra non-required symbols. But even input.split will work

Comment: The `strip` call will only remove whitespace on the front and back of the string, it will not affect the insides. However, this will work, because `split` does the right thing. The `strip` is unnecessary.